# QueryDSL SubQuery not working - IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value did not match expected type

Tags: hibernate, jpa, querydsl

I'm trying to run a query with a subquery in QueryDSL 4.1.4. The equivalent in version 3.x worked but I can't seem to get it to work in version 4.1.4. Not sure if I'm missing something or if there is a bug. Any input is appreciated!

Here is the relevant code:

```
PathBuilder productEntity = ...;
PathBuilder categoryEntity = ...;

JPQLQuery query = queryFactory.get().query();
query.distinct();

FilteredClause subQuery = JPAExpressions
    .select(productEntity.get("id", Long.class))
    .from(categoryEntity)
    .innerJoin(categoryEntity.get("products"), productEntity)
    .where(categoryEntity.get("id", Long.class).eq(categoryId));

query.where(productEntity.get("id", Long.class).notIn(subQuery));
query.fetch();
```

With the above, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [select product.id
from Category category
  inner join treat(category.products as Product) as product
where category.id = ?1] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long (n/a)]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.validateBinding(BaseQueryImpl.java:897)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.access$000(QueryImpl.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl$ParameterRegistrationImpl.bindValue(QueryImpl.java:235)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl$JpaPositionalParameterRegistrationImpl.bindValue(QueryImpl.java:371)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.setParameter(BaseQueryImpl.java:692)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:372)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy365.setParameter(Unknown Source)
    at com.querydsl.jpa.impl.JPAUtil.setConstants(JPAUtil.java:56)
    at com.querydsl.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.createQuery(AbstractJPAQuery.java:102)
    at com.querydsl.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.fetchCount(AbstractJPAQuery.java:81)
...
```

It seems like the whole subquery is set as parameter and Hibernate isn't happy about it. Is there a different QueryDSL syntax that I should be using to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the problem was the subquery being of type `FilteredClause`. It didn't cause any compile errors, so it might be something that could be better handled by Querydsl but after changing the subquery to the below things started working:

```
JPQLQuery subQuery = JPAExpressions
    .select(productEntity.get("id", Long.class))
    .from(categoryEntity)
    .innerJoin(categoryEntity.get("products"), productEntity);

// Keep the .where() call separate to retain the JPQLQuery object
subQuery.where(categoryEntity.get("id", Long.class).eq(categoryId));

// subQuery is now of type JPQLQuery instead of FilteredClause
query.where(productEntity.get("id", Long.class).notIn(subQuery));

List result = query.fetch();
```